GEE type casting / list creation and access to list-of-lists
I have difficulty in working (interchangeably) between client-side and server-side variables in GEE.
I have two lists (defined as client-side variables) :
var color_lst = ['604791', 'F648F1', '39a8a7'];
var code_lst = ['ABC', 'EFD', 'GEH'];

I want to pair these two lists with a function-map form :
var paired = ee.List.sequence(0, 2, 1).map(function(i){
    return [ee.List(color_lst).get(i), ee.List(code_lst).get(i)];
});

The result is a (server-side proxy object) list-of-lists:
print('paired list', paired);

How can I access the elements of of this list?
print('first element',paired.get(0));//This will return the object representing the first list inside 'paired'.

Next two lines will produce error:
print(ee.String(paired.get(0)[0]));
print(ee.String(paired.get(0).get(0)));


You could cast the list of lists in the paired object to List object using ee.List() and access the list elements
print(ee.List(paired.get(2)).get(0)) // prints 39a8a7
